# Getting started on Celestial Mechanics

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, celestial-mechanics

I am searching for a math-accurate book on this subject, in particular for this topics:

- $n$-body problem, getting more detailed when $n=2$.
- Efeméride calculation.
- Orbit determination.
- Perturbation theory.

I am a math student and this is the only physics-related course in my career so I need to read something really basic.

Comment: Are you already familiar with the Lagrangian and/ or Hamiltonian approach to mechanics?

Comment: No, not at all. This is the first time I have a course with some physics on it, apart from some examples in differential equations or some comments in differential geometry.

Comment: That's usually a prereq for the study of celestial mechanics.  You might try [*Mathematical Aspects of Classical and Celestial Mechanics* by Arnold, Kozlov, and Neishtadt](http://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Classical-Celestial-Mechanics-Encyclopaedia/dp/3540282467).  It aims at going over the relevant classical mechanics before handling celestial mechanics.  It does so rather quickly though.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just starting I recommend checking out Pollard's mathematical introduction to celestial mechanics and Szebehely's adventures in celestial mechanics.

Szebeheley's also has a detailed list of references. Also for Szebeheley's I think the first edition is better and the second edition got too long.